# Are finite moments of probability distributions preserved under continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $\nu \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is a probability measure with finite $j^\text{th}$ moment for some $j \geq 1$:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \|z\|^j \; d\nu(z) < \infty$$

Let $g: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function. Let $Z \sim \nu$ and consider the distribution $\gamma$ of $g(Z)$. Then is it also true that $\gamma$ has finite $j^\text{th}$ moment? Is it also true that:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \|x\|^j \; d\gamma(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \|g(z)\|^j \; d\nu(z) < \infty$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not follow that $\gamma$ also has finite $j^\text{th}$ moment. For example, consider $j=k=n=1,$ choose $\nu$ to have finite mean and infinite second moment (e.g. let $\nu$ have the density $f(x)=(3/2)x^{-5/2}$ on the interval from $1$ to infinity) and let $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R:x\mapsto x^2.$

In your second display, doing a change of variables yields your equality. However, as you see, the $<\infty$ inequality may not be true.